# Need a help to identify the cost to create a virtual machine in Azure Dev-Test LAB as well the availability to install require software

Tags: azure, microsoft-dynamics, azure-virtual-machine, dynamics-365, azure-devtest-labs

I need to create a virtual machine regarding the development of Dynamics CRM.
I need the below software into the Virtual Machine.

1. Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition
2. Microsoft Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Extension
3. Google Chrome Web Browser
4. Microsoft Office
5. Adobe Reader

Can someone help me to identify that? Can I install the above things into the Azure Virtual Machine in Azure DevTest Lab?

If yes, then how much would the cost be to use the above-configured virtual machine?

I need a virtual machine should have (4 cores and 8GB of RAM).
Any help would much be appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever tried checking out [Microsoft Azure's Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/) for the Virtual Machines? I think you'd easily find your answer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/). While you're at it, you should also check out the services that the [Virtual Machine](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/) provides.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is perfectly possible and it can be easily achieved using [Visual Studio preconfigured VM's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/using-visual-studio-vm).

The VM size shouldn't be lower than a D2 v3 (in a recent project we used D4 and I was quite happy with its performance) which costs around $154/month. Of course, this is the price for the VM working 24x7 but price can go down substantially if you turn off the VM outside working hours (it can go down to around $45/month). You can estimate how many hours the VM will be needed and then calculate the price using [this information](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/).

If you're looking to use the [Dynamics 365 Report Authoring Extension](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50375), please be aware that the latest Visual Studio version its supports is 2015. If you still want to use 2017 on your development, you can have a separate VM specific for reporting with VS 2015 and BIDS. Preconfigured VM's support both version so it's not a problem, and again, as you're only paying for a VM when is on, you won't double your costs by taking this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I need the licensing price estimates in details i.e How much Google Chrome cost us as well as the Adobe reader cost because I can not see these items in the Azure Price Calculator and also I can not see the Visual Studio costs.

Comment: Visual Studio preconfigured VM's don't include VS license: “Visual Studio follows the “bring your own license” model in Azure”. Other third party licenses are also not included in the price, so it will depends on the licensing model of each application you want to install on your VM.